# TextInfo for Neutral Culture - how is the region of the non-neutral culture determined?

Tags: .net, globalization, cultureinfo

Consider this code:

```
new CultureInfo("sv").TextInfo.CultureName
```

This returns "sv-SE". But why? Why not "sv-FI" or some other culture? How is the region determined?

The [documentation for CultureName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/SV-SE/library/system.globalization.textinfo.culturename.aspx) says

> If CultureInfo.Name has a neutral culture as its value, then the
>   corresponding CultureName has as its value an arbitrary specific
>   culture that uses the same language. For example, the Name property
>   returns "en" for the English neutral culture, but the corresponding
>   CultureName property might return "en-US" for the English (United
>   States) culture.

It's not clear how the region is chosen. For "en", the chose region is "US", resulting in the culture en-US.

This seems like a nifty way of automatically getting the "primary" region for a language - but is that really what it does? Or is it completely random that sv-SE and en-US are chosen? The word "might" seems rather too vague to rely on.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx

Cultures in .Net have an ID where the last 10 bits defines the language while the other bits define the region.

for English the language id is 9 and en_US has an ID of 0x0409 - en_GB has 0x0809

so I guess if you don't provide and region it just takes the first according to the ID

```
CultureID = LanguageID + 0x0400
```

the same fits also for sv-SE and sv-FI

Comment: Interesting. Since the `TextInfo` workaround is a bit of a hack, is there a more direct route to the default region for a language or a neutral culture? That is, a way of getting the 0x0400+language culture without using `TextInfo`?

Comment: @bzlm not sure I understood your question, there is the [LCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid.aspx) in culture info. Which is the ID of the Language + Region. You can use this LCID also to create a new culture info instance. I use it in a web application for the language ID since it's easier to work with numbers than characters. Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

The underlying data for language neutral maps back to a given specific language which you can find out by calling System.Globalization.Cultureinfo.CreateSpecificCulture with the neutral language. As to why, there is some attempt to map to the region with the most speakers but it may also have to do with initial support for the language--the first supported dialect ends up being the primary. In any case, it isn't something that changes once established. Why would you want to determine a primary region for a language?